# AWS API Gateway with CloudWatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I've been tinkering with AWS API Gateway for creating a rest api for one of my projects.

I've managed to connect it to DynamoDB Queries and to launch Lambda functions quite easily. 
However one of my ideas is to be able to create CloudWatch Event Rules though it but i have not been able to set this up yet.

I want to be able to create a new scheduled task for a lambda though api gateway. The scheduled task should be a cron task.

I've been reading the documentation but i feel stuck. I know that I can solve it using another lambda but I would like to avoid it as CloudWatch Events exists as one of the connected AWS Services.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)?

Comment: OMG... This looks like what i'm looking for!
I'll test it out now

Comment: @Stargazer this was not what I was looking for :( Or I am at least still stuck at actually passing though the information to create a new rule

Comment: So, it is not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I think that i figured it out.. I don't think it's possible to create a rule and a target using a single request. I need to create the rule and the target separately and It does not seem like API Gateway allows for multiple requests for one request. 

I want to create a Rule for a specific (hardcoded) target.